# get_job_info() giving item not found error : python-jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, python-3.6

I am using [python-jenkins](http://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and python 3.6

Trying to get the information regarding the jobs in jenkins but facing an error.

> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jenkins/**init**.py",
>   line 359, in get_job_info
>       self._build_url(JOB_INFO, locals())   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jenkins/**init**.py", line
>   451, in jenkins_open
>       raise NotFoundException('Requested item could not be found') jenkins.NotFoundException: Requested item could not be found

```
jobs = server.get_all_jobs()
for j in jobs:
    jobName = j['name'] # get job name
    print(jobName)
    lastJobId = getLastJobId(session, jobName) # get last locally stored job of this name
    print(lastJobId)
    lastBuildNumber = server.get_job_info(jobName)
```

get_all_jobs() is working fine but [get_job_info()](http://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#jenkins.Jenkins.get_job_info) is not working.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to use the `fullname` key instead of the `name` key.

```
jobName = j['fullname'] # get job name
```

There could be multiple jobs with the same job name, but in different folders/views. And `fullname` will fully qualify a specific job.